# Is "The Tomorrow War" based on any book?

Tags: the-tomorrow-war

I know there was a lot of social media speculation before the movie release on whether "The Tomorrow War" Amazon film is based on any book (Scalzi and Haldeman were mentioned often), due to various plot similarities.

**Is there any official information on that?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [an interview with Slash Film](https://www.slashfilm.com/tomorrow-war-writer-interview/), the screenwriter, Zach Dean, seems to indicate that it was an original work, inspired by his experience as a father of three children:

> SLASH FILM: I’ll go to one of my ’90s touchstones: *Independence Day*, a movie that I love because it could be very silly. It often asks you to make big leaps, but it never talks down to itself. When you’re writing this, how much are you aware that this could become a parody of itself if you’re not careful?
>
> ZACH DEAN: Well, I think what grounds it, it’s about a family, honestly. I mean, I think at its core, it deals with all this stuff, it deals with all these larger issues.. But at the end of the day, it’s a family story about a family that has fractures in it, and a man who has to figure out how to be a father while looking at the father that is not necessarily the one he thought he wanted, and then he has to figure out how to be a father to his kid. And so, I think that, as long as you stay in a true place where it matters, which is why it made a pleasure to write, **it was a story that came very naturally, it’s an original thing. I do mostly original work and it just felt like… I have three kids, I’m trying to figure out how to be a dad all the time, and that just felt like a really real place to come from.**